# Subscribe to observable in new model

Tags: knockout.js

In my ViewModel, I'm dealing with 3 different model observables.

Everything works, except I have an observable where I am trying to notify the user, on lost focus of the input (or some event), that the value should be a whole number, if it isn't. I also plan to use this same logic to send an ajax request.

I've never tried to work with an empty observable before, so I'm a little confused as to if I should just bind an event handler on it or how I should go about it.

### Model :

```
    var deferredAccount = function() {
            var self = this;

            self.Id = ko.observable();
            self.accountNumber = ko.observable();
            self.participantId = ko.observable();
            self.taxPercentage = ko.observable();

        }
```

### ViewModel : (a lot of other things removed)

```
newAccount = ko.observable();
newAccount(new model.DeferredAccount());   <-- to the View
```

### Relevant HTML

```
    <form class="form-horizontal" data-bind="with: newAccount">

                    <label class=" col-sm-5 control-label">Account Number: </label>
                    <input data-bind="value: accountNumber" class="col-sm-3 form-control" type="text" />

                    <label class=" col-sm-5 control-label">Tax Percentage: </label>
                    <input id="percent" data-bind="value: taxPercentage" class="col-sm-3 form-control" type="text" min="0" max="85" title="Enter Percentage in Decimal Format"/>
    </form>
```

For `taxPercentage`, I want to validate that field on `lostFocus` or at *some* point. I think because I'm not used to working with so many different moving pieces I am getting confused on how to access the appropriate observable.

Comment: I think you just want to create a computedObservable that does the test. It will be recomputed whenever the value changes and the field loses focus. Depends on what you want to do in response to validation.

See also: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html

Comment: @RoyJ Thanks, Roy. You were correct with the extenders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for an extender. Extenders are filters that you put between your view and your observable.

The knockout docs describe the process nicely and even have [a fully implemented extender for rounding numbers](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html) that you can simply use:

```
var deferredAccount = function() {
    var self = this;

    self.Id = ko.observable();
    self.accountNumber = ko.observable();
    self.participantId = ko.observable();
    self.taxPercentage = ko.observable().extend({numeric: 0});

}
```

and

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" data-bind="with: newAccount">
    <label class="col-sm-5 control-label">Account Number: </label>
    <input data-bind="value: accountNumber" class="col-sm-3 form-control" type="text" />

    <label class=" col-sm-5 control-label">Tax Percentage: </label>
    <input id="percent" data-bind="value: taxPercentage" class="col-sm-3 form-control" type="text" min="0" max="85" title="Enter Percentage in Decimal Format"/>

</form>
```

No special event-handling necessary.

To enforce min- and max values, look into the [knockout-validation project](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation).

Comment: Let me give it a whirl. 1 sec. And thanks for answering, by the way.

Comment: Okay, so I see how it all works, however, when I new up a model in my ViewModel, do I need to add the `.extend()` onto the specific property? I'm using `RequireJS` so my files aren't necessary concise like the examples (I created a new js file and threw the extend method in it, and threw that file in the bundle)

Comment: You need to extend the observable(s) that you would like to behave differently. I don't see why require.js would make any difference here.